# How to submit mutiple items to paypal page during checkout PHP

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

```
    while ( $CART = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $q_cart ) ) {
    $cart_data .= '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $CART ['cart_id'] . '">
                  <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' . $CART ['productID'] . '">
                  <input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="' . $CART ['price'] . '">
                  <input type="hidden" name="item_name' . $i . '" value="' . $CART ['product_name'] . '">
                  <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $i . '" value="' . number_format ( $CART ['price'], 2 ). '">
                  <input type="hidden" name="quantity' . $i . '" value="' . $CART ['quantity'] . '">
                  <table width="600px"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                  <tr>
                      <td valign="top" align="left" width="55%" class="font_st_color"><a href="cart.php?prod_id=' . $CART ['productID'] . '" title="' . $CART ['product_name'] . '">' . $CART ['product_name'] . '</a></td>
                      <td align="center" width="15%" class="padding">' . $CART ['quantity'] . '</td>
                      <td align="center" width="15%" class="pad_st_color"><b>$ ' . number_format ( $CART ['price'], 2 ) . '</b></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  ';
    $i += 1;
}
```

What I get from research is that item_name_1 = "Item1" that is why I doing a variable i but I am when I link to checkout page Quantity:1 by right should be 2 and the item name doens appear it appeared Enter Description, Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `cmd` and `upload` fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-cart-upload.html#HTMLVariablesOnlyfortheCartUploadCommand